# wp_insert_user() function password never match

Tags: plugin-development, login, password

I am trying to use wp_insert_user() to add a user from the custom registration form.
The user gets added to the database with a hashed password, but when the user is logged out and tries to use another custom login form to log in the password never matches.
Here is the code to add the user:

```
$userdata = array(
    'user_login' =>  $username,
    'user_email' =>  $email,
    'user_pass'  =>  $password,
    'first_name' =>  $fname,
    'last_name'  =>  $lname,
    'show_admin_bar_front' => false
);
```

For login:

```
$info = array();
$info['user_login'] = $username;
$info['user_password'] = $values['password'];
$info['remember'] = true;
$user = get_user_by( 'email', $values['email'] );
if(isset($values['email'])){
    if ( $user && wp_check_password( $values['password'], $user->data->user_pass, $user->ID ) ) {
        $exists = email_exists( $values['email'] );
        if ( $exists ) {
            $user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );
            if ( !is_wp_error($user_signon) ){
                wp_set_current_user($user_signon->ID);
                wp_set_auth_cookie($user_signon->ID);
                wp_send_json(array(  // send JSON back
                  'loggedin' => true,
                  'message' => __('Login successful, redirecting...')
                ));
            }
        } else {
            wp_send_json(array(  // send JSON back
              'loggedin' => false,
              'message' => __('Email dont exist')
            ));
        }   
    } else {
        wp_send_json(array(  // send JSON back
          'message' => __( 'Email or password didnt match', 'diasporarestart-gd' ),
          'data'    => $values['password']
        ));
    }
}
```

P.S I confirm that my user exist. Wordpress just cant validate the password.
Regards,